# Order pairs by shared values

Tags: r

Let's get this data.frame from the scrambled one below (i.e. `df.sample`):

```
df
# > df
#      a   b
# 1 <NA> tre
# 2  tre pop
# 3  pop 123
# 4  123 ggg
```

The first row must be the one with an NA in column "a". Subsequently, the rule here is that each value from the `b` column is the same as the value in the `a` column in the following row.

Consider the same data with scrambled rows:

```
df.sample
# > df.sample
#      a   b
# 1  tre pop
# 2  123 ggg
# 3  pop 123
# 4 <NA> tre
```

How to order the pairs in succession (i.e. get from `df.sample` to `df`), observing the rule that the value in column `b` in one pair is the same as the value in the `a` column in the following pair?

**EDIT:** The solution should work for whatever value of the seed (see code for `df.sample` below). I.e. I want to get to `df` from `df.sample` given regardless of the seeed value.

---

Data:

```
df = data.frame(a = c(NA, "tre", "pop", "123"),
                b = c("tre", "pop", "123", "ggg"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
set.seed(1)
df.sample = dplyr::sample_n(df, 4)
rownames(df.sample) = NULL
```

Comment: Can you show an expected output?

Comment: I see I was a bit unclear. The expected output is just `df`. But how to order the rows of `df.sample` to get there - not by providing indexes manually, but by some function that figures out how the rows should be ordered based on the rule that, in each pair of values, the value in `a` is the same as the value in `b` of the preceding row.

Comment: @Jota if I `set.seed(4)`, your solution does not give me `df` out of `df.sample`. Moreover, it scrambles the pairs: `<NA> tre` becomes `<NA> 123` which I don't want.

Comment: The thing is, you are not allowed to break the pairs. Take `df.sample` and reorder rows in such a way that it becomes identical with `df`. Your solution must hold for any seed that the `df.sample` is created with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, we know the first row has to be the one with NA in column "a":

```
# create the new data frame to be filled in
newdf <- df.sample
newdf[] <- NA
(newdf[1, ] <- df.sample[is.na(df.sample$a), ])
#     a   b
#1 <NA> tre
```

From there, you have a structure with the appropriate number of rows to fill in, and you already know the first row.  So, it's a matter of working through and assigning each of the subsequent rows with the appropriate match.  One way, is to use a for loop:

```
for( i in seq_len(nrow(df.sample))[-1L] ) {
  newdf[i, ] <- df.sample[match(newdf[i - 1L, "b"], df.sample[["a"]]), ]
}
newdf
#     a   b
#2 <NA> tre
#4  tre pop
#3  pop 123
#1  123 ggg
```

Comment: Yep, using `match` is kind of obvious - at least now it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
df.sample %>%
  mutate(c = lead(a, n=1)) %>%
  select(a,c)
```

Of course, your example suggests edge cases are left as `NA` , so they are not handled in the solution either.

---

If you always generate `df.sample` by sampling from `df` , you can use:

```
df.sample %>%
  arrange(row.names(.)) %>%
  mutate(c = lead(a, n=1)) %>%
  select(a,c)
```

which will order the output per your requirement.

Comment: The `NA` is not an edge case. It is the starting point. Plus the ordering function should work even after setting different seed when generating the random order for the rows in `df.sample`. (basically, the same objection as the comment to Jota's solution).

Comment: yes, it does work in all those cases as well. you can try the code for different seeding options, which is why i didn;t provide any outputs here.
Also, I didn't say `NA` is the edge case. I said edge cases would result in `NA` . i.e., last value in the new column (here denoted by `c`) will be `NA` because there's nothing to match in the column `a`

Comment: For seed 4 your solution gives me the following pairs: `pop <NA>`, `<NA>  123`, `123  tre`, `tre <NA>`, _none of which_ appears in `df`. I want to get `df` from `df.sample` for any given seed. But point taken about the NA's.

Comment: i see it now. my code generates output based on the rule you mention. but seems you also want a specific sequence for the rows. will update shortly.

Comment: I updated my question. I will never have correct rownames at my disposal.

Comment: This is fun! What governs the sequence of rows in the final output? is it always static?

Comment: Well, it has to be static. If we start at the row with NA, which has the value "tre" in `b`, then the following row *has* to be "tre - pop", because no other row starts with "tre". What I want is an algorithm that will follow this rule and order `df.sample` according to it, so that you end up with `df`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134579/discussion-between-aramis7d-and-jakub).